# Find the constant term in the expansion of $\left(x^2 + x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{15}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

Find the constant term in the expansion of $$\left(x^2 + x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{15}$$

I know the answer is

> $$ \sum _{k = 0}^{5} \binom{15}{5+k}\binom{15}{3k} =68974906 $$

Comment: Just apply the multinomial theorem. Or are you curious as to how to find the sum?

Comment: I tried that, it gives a 4 variable sum with constraint. From there I can't proceed.

Comment: @dark32 Please explain. How are you getting that $4$-variable sum? Note that you only have to consider the products in which the exponents sum up to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\left[x^0\right]\left(x^2+x+\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}\right)^{15}
&=\left[x^0\right]\left(\frac1{x^{30}}(x+1)^{15}\left(x^3+1\right)^{15}\right)\\
&=\left[x^{30}\right]\left((x+1)^{15}\left(x^3+1\right)^{15}\right)\\
&=\left[x^{30}\right]\sum_{k,j}\binom{15}{j}\binom{15}{k}x^{3k+j}\\
&=\sum_{3k+j=30}\binom{15}{j}\binom{15}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=5}^{10}\binom{15}{30-3k}\binom{15}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{15}{15-3k}\binom{15}{k+5}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{15}{3k}\binom{15}{k+5}\\
\end{align}
$$